# yii2 ul li menu sorting with foreach value

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

i am using ul li to display menus, menus fetched from database

```
$Features = $session->get('Features');
foreach ($Features as $menuItems) {
   $order_priority = $menuItems->order_priority;
   $name = $menuItems->name;
   $path = $menuItems->path;
}
```

here below the menu listed ,

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo Url::to($path);?>">
    <?php echo $menuItems->name; ?>
  </a>
</li>
```

my question is i want to display the menu SORT with order_priority `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: Try to sort items in DB query or use array sort functions
like http://php.net/manual/ro/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

If your order_priority attribute doesn't repeats. You can try this:

```
$menu = [];
foreach ($session->get('Features') as $menuItems) {
    $menu[$menuItems->order_priority] = Html::a($menuItems->name, $menuItems->path);

}
ksort($menu);
```

And for generate the list, you can do like this:

```
echo Html::ul($menu)
```

But if it does repeat, you could sort the items in your db query like @ustmaestro said in the comments.